# python won't accept the value of a variable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This runs and scrapes links exactly how I want it except python doesn't recognize the value of "scraped_pages" when I run it in the terminal scraped pages will increment by 1 every loop but it just carries on when the integer is higher than "page_nums". when I set "page_nums" to an integer below 5 it will run and stop at 5 but any more and it will crash. I apologize if I've not worded the question the best I've been up all night on this.
All code above this is working this is the problem code. All modules are imported correctly also.
It uses selenium, I'm not sure the explicit wait is working since it crashes before it will reach the "page_nums" value.

```
page_nums = raw_input("how many pages to scrape?: ")
urls_list = []
scraped_pages = 0
scraped_links = 0

while scraped_pages <= page_nums:
    for li in list_items:
        for a in li.find_all('a', href=True):
            url = a['href']
            if slicer(url,'http'):
                url1 = slicer(url,'http')
                urls_list.append(url1)
                scraped_links += 1
            elif slicer(url,'www'):
                url1 = slicer(url,'www')
                urls_list.append(url1)
                scraped_links += 1
            else:
                pass
    scraped_pages += 1
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[12]")))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[12]").click()
    print scraped_links
print urls_list
```

Here is part of the error returned.

```
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google page click 2.py", line 51, in <module>
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[12]").click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 75, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 454, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpzSHEeb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9981)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpzSHEeb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12517)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpzSHEeb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpzSHEeb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpzSHEeb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because Selenium has successfully loaded a webpage, but the button you are trying to click is 'not in view'. There are two likely scenarios:

**1.** If, for some reason, the element is hidden (ie hidden via CSS), then you will not be able to click it.

**2.** The element might not be visible because it is in part of the webpage that you have to scroll to view. To circumvent this issue you can use:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[12]")))
element_to_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[12]")
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', element_to_click)
element_to_click.click()
```

The third line executes some JavaScript which scrolls the element into view before you ask Selenium to click it. If you are using this script on hundreds/thousands of webpages then you may want to put use `time.sleep(1)` before `element_to_click.click()`, thus giving the browser time to scroll the element into view before attempting to click it.

As an aside, you should do a little reading on XPaths - it is a lot easier to try and select elements by `id` or `class` name eg:

```
//div[@id="some-id"]
```

Selects the element in the document with `id="some-id"`.

Comment: It actually says in the question that i've used impliit and explicit waits.

Comment: Agreed - doesn't rule out my potential answer though? Can you provide me with more info so I can replicate your problem?